# Gerrit allow submit if label greater than 0 (prolog rule)

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I have created a custom label in Gerrit.

```
[label "Code-Quality"]
  function = NoOp
  value =  0 No score
  value = +1 Horror
  value = +2 Not bad
  value = +3 Good
  value = +4 Super Hiper
  value = +5 Jon Skeet
```

This is intended to see (in the long term) who is considered to write a good quality code. However, when I have left this label optional (`NoOp`), nobody seemed to fill it. Gerrit displays a <kbd>CodeReview +2</kbd> shortcut button so reviewers in most cases do not even open the <kbd>Reply</kbd> box where they would see the additional label.

What I want to achieve is to block the change submission unless the `CQ` flag is set to any value greater than 0 by the reviewer(s). The [`AnyWithBlock`](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_function) function seems reasonable if I add `-1` value to this flag, but reviewers still can skip setting it (often unintentionally) with the shortcut button.

I have seen [I can create a custom submit rule in prolog](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#HowToWriteSubmitRules). However, although there are many examples of many different rules, no one fits my use case. Also, the prolog syntax looks so mysterious to me that I wasn't able to produce anything even close to my need.

Any help with writing such submission rule or pointing me into another direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
[label "Code-Quality"]
  function = AnyWithBlock
  defaultValue = -1
  value = -1 No score
  value = +1 Horror
  value = +2 Not bad
  value = +3 Good
  value = +4 Super Hiper
  value = +5 Jon Skeet
```

Comment: As I said, this does not work when reviewer uses the `Code-Review+2` button. The `defaultValue` specifies only which radio option is selected by default in the Reply box.

Comment: But if the user click only in the Code-Review+2 button the change won't be approved, will it? What is the Code-Quality value after the user click in the Code-Review+2 button? Is it 0 or -1?

Comment: The change is approved then. The value of CQ is 0 in such case. Gerrit treats it as "user haven't chosen anything". I am started to think that it is a Gerrit's bug...

Comment: I have reported [an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=4733).

Comment: Yes, IMHO it's a kindy of bug because "no value" is not the same of "any value".

Comment: *The "true" default value for any label is 0, which also means: this label was never set yet. So the best solution for your case would be to add a prolog rule to ensure CQ has a value greater than zero.* - states an answer to [the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=4733#c1).

Comment: As a workaround, you can set a hook (or something) to vote CQ = -1 for every change pushed.